# Why Is VS2019 / VB.Net /EF 6 Requiring a Doubling Up on My Imports?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, webforms

After a multi-year layoff I'm trying to pick back up an application I originally worked on using VSEW 2012 in VB.NET Web Forms against .NET 4.5.1 and EF 5.0.  The app recompiled nicely using VS2019 and .NET 4.7.2 until I started trying to "modernize" things, and then all heck broke loose.  When I upgraded to EF 6, entity-related "not defined" messages came up by the hundreds.  Ah, I see EF5 -> EF6 isn't quite so seamless.

So, to help determine what's going on, I went back and created a new simple Web Forms app and generated an EF 6.2 model from my existing database.  All is good - but to use my Entity Container (in the below, AlphaEntities) I have to "double up" the Root Namespace for the project on the Imports statement.  Never had to do anything like that before.

I guess I'm just rusty - but what am I missing?  I think the answer on this simple app will help me determine what needs to be fixed on my "real" app.

```vb
Imports TestWebApp1.TestWebApp1 '<=== Note Root Namespace Doubled Up

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Using dbc As New AlphaEntities
            testLabel.Text = dbc.Customers.First.Name.ToString
    End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT: After a night's sleep, I found the part of the project configuration dialog that sets imported namespaces (which wasn't immediately visible, given how my VS windows are arranged) and selected the "doubled up" TestWebApp1.TestWebApp1 namespace.  Now the entity container reference correctly compiles without the explicit Imports reference.  So I checked my old VSEW 2012 configuration on another laptop and a) it did not require the root namespace to be checked/imported this way, and b) there was not even a "doubled up" option displayed to be imported. So, I'm still unclear why a) I needed to import the namespace in the project config at all (has something changed in this regard since VS2012?), and b) TestWebApp1.TestWebApp1 needs to be imported and not just TestWebApp1.

Comment: What is in the field "Root namespace" under the properties of the project?

Comment: @the_lotus It is "TestWebApp1" (and my project is called "TestWebApp" i.e., no "1" appended to the end - I changed the namespace to differentiate between the two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some exploration in the VS Object Browser, it turned out that the generated EF part of the entity (partial) classes were for some reason apparently not "merging" into the remainder of the (partial) classes that I was was creating in separate files.  Object Browser showed two different classes in the hierarchy for each entity.  Removing the project's Root Namespace solved this issue, although it's unclear to me exactly why this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

What I compile in VB on 2019 will not compile on Azure pipeline.   So this is a real problem.

I ended up dropping out a project from my solution as I could not reconcile a good solution to the above and it was testing code.    In another project I migrated out to a C# library eliminating the issue entirely.   It is a VB issue alone.